# WPF change progressbar foreground colour

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with the progressbar and I am trying to find a way of setting the foreground colour to red if the showError variable (bool) in the label below it is true. I can set the foreground colour based on the progress bar value using a data trigger, as shown below but I cannot capture the value in the showError variable. Anybody managed to do this?

```
    <ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Max}" Minimum="{Binding Min}" Name="progressBar" Value="{Binding Path=Value}" >
        <ProgressBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}" Value="10">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ProgressBar.Resources>
    </ProgressBar>
    <Label Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowError, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Content="Service was not available" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,238,0,0" Name="label2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ShowError` is a property of your view model. As such, you don't need any relationship between the `ProgressBar` and the `Label`. Just use something like this:

```
<ProgressBar>
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowError}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. ShowError is a property of my viewmodel. Many thanks. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

As both your label and the progress bar are bind to the View Model Property ShowError, you don't need to make the label and progress bar dependent on each other.

Regards
Jashobanta